# Finding all $23$rd roots of a given element of $S_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Given the permutation 
>   $$\sigma = 
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
> 1 &2 &3 &7 &5 &6 &4 &8 &9 &10
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   solve the equation $$\gamma^{23} = \sigma ,$$
>   where $\sigma,\gamma \in S_{10}$

What I did: $\sigma $ in cycle notation is $(47)$ i.e a transposition.The order of $\sigma$ is 2 because the length of the cycle is 2, so that means $\sigma$ his it's own inverse (I think) i.e $\sigma \circ\sigma = e$.

Taking the equation $\gamma^{23} = \sigma$ and multiplying on the right by $\sigma$ I get  $\gamma^{23} \circ \sigma = e$ , so that means that $\gamma^{23}$ and $\sigma$ are inverses , that implies that $\gamma$ must be  equal to $\sigma$ since the order of $\sigma$ is 2 and $\gamma^{22} = \gamma^{24} = e$ since 22 and 24 are divided by the order of $\sigma$ , so the only option is $\gamma = \sigma$.

Is that correct?Is there another way of solving this type of equations? I doubt it's right.

Comment: The problem with your argument may become more apparent if you realize that it is wrong in $S_{25}$. If $\gamma\in S_{25}$ is the disjoint product of the 2-cycle $(47)$ and **any** $23$-cycle, then $\gamma^{23}=(47)$. So in $S_{25}$ there are at least $22!$ solutions. As Travis explained, there is no room $S_{10}$ for such solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\sigma$ is a transposition, any solution $\gamma$ satisfies $e = \sigma^2 = (\gamma^{23})^2 = \gamma^{46} .$ The prime factorization of $46$ is $2 \cdot 23$, so $\gamma$ has order $1$ (not possible, since $e^{23} = e \neq \sigma$), $2$, $23$ or $46$.

Every element of $S_{10}$ has order dividing $|S_{10}| = 10!$. Now, $23$, being a prime larger than $10$, does not divide $10!$, so...

> ...$\gamma$ cannot have order $23$ or $46 = 2 \cdot 23$. Thus, it has order $2$, and so $$\sigma = \gamma^{23} = (\gamma^2)^{11} \gamma = e^{11} \gamma = \gamma .$$

Comment: Oh, that's a much nicer way of solving it, is there a common algorithm that I can use for those types of equations ?

Comment: Certainly I've partly described a partial algorithm here. Given a general equation $\gamma^k = \sigma$, we have $\gamma^{k \cdot o(\sigma)} = e$, which gives possible orders of $\gamma$ and discard orders that have a prime factor that does not divide the order of the group. In each case we get some reduced equation $\gamma^{k'} = \sigma$. For $S_n$ we can then write down each conjugacy class whose elements have the given order, determine the conjugacy class of $\gamma^{k'}$, and throw out those that don't match $\sigma$. For modest $n$ this can all be done by hand.

Comment: I understand now, thank you !